# Show div on page after clicking on Mailchimp submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a MailChimp form embedded on a static HTML page and I want the section that has the form to show a "Thank you" message after they enter their email and submit.

Mind you, on clicking the submit form, a Mailchimp confirmation page opens in a new tab. But on the page, I would like to have a hidden div show like below...

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYUIU.jpg)

Some of the examples I see require adding an id to the button but MailChimp already requires an id on the  element.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Seizedev/j3vofubr/7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<div id="join">
  <form action="" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email">

    <button type="submit" value="subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">Subscribe</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="success-msg" style="display: none;">
  <p>Thanks for joining! We’ll stay in touch.</p>
  <a class="share-btn" href="">Share</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to do this with jquery using an example

```
<script>
    $('#btnClick').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#join-tour').css('display') != 'none') {
            $('#success-msg').html($('#success-msg').html()).show().siblings('div').hide();
        } else if ($('#2').css('display') != 'none') {
            $('#join-tour').show().siblings('div').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the javascript you're working with?

Comment: You forgot to add your js/jquery.

Comment: My JS is really poor :(
I was basically trying to use other people's code

Comment: @justDan Thanks! I was actually looking to hide the input field and just show the success message. Im going to try and edit your fiddle to get that working

Comment: @SeizeDev So hide the input field but what about the subscribe button? Keep it displayed or hide that as well? Here's that fiddle link again if you need it: https://jsfiddle.net/3eczqkfd/1/. That one actually hides the whole `#join` section on submit.

Comment: Like when you click on the MailChimp submit button, let it hide the entire div that contains the input field and button and just show the div with the Success message.

Comment: Ok. Try that last fiddle I just posted in the above comment.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/3eczqkfd/1 It works! Thanks justDan